# What is the correct French noun for a school report?

Tags: vocabulaire, éducation

What is the correct French noun for a school report? A school report is the report on a child's progress written by a teacher.

Comment: Can you define, give a context, for "school report"?  Without context, it's difficult to translate. "bulletin scolaire" would be a possible answer.

Comment: Which kind of "report" do you mean? Do you mean a report ON the student's progress, like a report card? Or do you mean a report BY the student as a work project?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mean areport on a child's progress by a teacher

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the context:

- carnet de notes (mostly used in primary school)
- relevé de notes (quite general)
- bulletin, or bulletin scolaire (primary/middle school)

Answer (score 2):

In France, we say *bulletin scolaire* or *carnet de notes* (mostly for children under 11 or 12).

Answer (score 2):

The expression *relevé de notes* is also used, mainly for students.

Answer (score 2):

Tiens, justement je viens de signer ce matin le *livret d'évaluation* de ma fille en maternelle. Apparemment, c'est un document qui suit l'élève sur tout un cycle, c'est-à-dire plusieurs années.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for "bulletin scolaire"
See http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_scolaire